# What is the reaction steps taken when producing auroral forcing?

Tags: photochemistry, radicals, ionization-energy, atmospheric-chemistry

As described in here:

https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2018/sounding-rocket-mission-will-trace-auroral-winds

A mixture of Trimethylaluminium, Barium and Strontium reacts and ionize in the upper atmosphere to produce the spectral emission seen. What is the exact reaction pathway taking place?

Comment: There is some information on strontium and barium here: an earlier version of the publication below, freely available on the web, appeared in Journal of Pyrotechnics, No. 18, 2003. Color Values and Spectra of the Principal Emitters in Colored Flames, W. Meyerriecks* and K. L. Kosanke.

Comment: The chemical reaction is close to irrelevant -- high-energy ions and electrons in the aurora knock apart the chemical compounds, leaving free ions of Al, Ba and Sr, if the chemicals are sufficiently dispersed.